# pgfplots: show x tick labels for data below ymin

Tags: plot, bar-chart, tikz-pgf

I have a very simple bar chart plot. My problem is when I set a ymin value, all x labels whose values are below that threshold will not be displayed. I'd rather have the labels but no values shown.

mini example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin = 5,
    xtick=data,
    symbolic x coords={a,b,c},
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(a,7) (b,9) (c,4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]
[image]

left picture no ymin, right picture with ymin

Can anybody tell me how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really [shouldn't use bar charts if your axis doesn't start at zero](http://www.storytellingwithdata.com/2012/09/bar-charts-must-have-zero-baseline.html) (that defeats the purpose of using bars and opens up the door to all sorts of misrepresentation of data).

That said, here's a way of doing it anyway: You can use `restrict y to domain*=5:inf` to truncate the values at the lower axis limits (values that are below the threshold value are assigned the threshold value). That way, all bars will be plotted, some with a height of zero. To make sure these bars aren't visible, it's a good idea to set `axis on top` in the `axis` options.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
    axis on top,
    ybar,
    ymin = 5,
    restrict y to domain*=5:inf,
    xtick=data,
    symbolic x coords={a,b,c}
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(a,7) (b,9) (c,4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this works perfect for me. Btw. you are right with your remark on not using bar charts with non-zero based axis. I however need this for realizing a broken axis by puttin two diagrams on top of each other.